# Moving a a character on a map using list indexes

Tags: python

For a feature in the game I need to make, there needs to be a map in the form of a grid. It is a nested list with positions called `_map`. To display the map in grid form, I used the `map_grid` function.

Secondly, the game should allow the user to move the character from cell to cell by prompting the user to input `w`, `A`, `S` and `D` keys (up, down, left, right respectively). The character starts at `_map[0][0]`, at the top left and if, for example, the input is `S`, the character's position will change to `_map[1][0]` and be represented in the grid according to that position. The problem is that I'm not sure how to increment the values in the inner and outer list.

Also if anyone could suggest a better way to display the map (perhaps maybe with loops?) instead of manually printing everything out, it would be appreciated because I know the code I've written is lengthy and difficult to read.

```py
_map = [
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
    [' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' '],\
    [' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'K']\
]

def map_grid(_map):
    print("+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |"
          .format(_map[0][0],_map[0][1],_map[0][2],_map[0][3],_map[0][4],_map[0][5],_map[0][6],_map[0][7]))
    print("+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
          .format(_map[1][0],_map[1][1],_map[1][2],_map[1][3],_map[1][4],_map[1][5],_map[1][6],_map[1][7]))
    print("| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
          .format(_map[2][0],_map[2][1],_map[2][2],_map[2][3],_map[2][4],_map[2][5],_map[2][6],_map[2][7]))
    print("| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
          .format(_map[3][0],_map[3][1],_map[3][2],_map[3][3],_map[3][4],_map[3][5],_map[3][6],_map[3][7]))
    print("| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
          .format(_map[4][0],_map[4][1],_map[4][2],_map[4][3],_map[4][4],_map[4][5],_map[4][6],_map[4][7]))
    print("| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
          .format(_map[5][0],_map[5][1],_map[5][2],_map[5][3],_map[5][4],_map[5][5],_map[5][6],_map[5][7]))
    print("| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
          .format(_map[6][0],_map[6][1],_map[6][2],_map[6][3],_map[6][4],_map[6][5],_map[6][6],_map[6][7]))
    print("| {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {} |\n+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
          .format(_map[7][0],_map[7][1],_map[7][2],_map[7][3],_map[7][4],_map[7][5],_map[7][6],_map[7][7]))

def move(_map, map_grid):
    hero_position = _map[0][0]
    move_direction = input("Press WASD to move: ")
    if move_direction == "d":
        hero_position = _map[1][+1]
        print(hero_position)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start from the secondary question you had. Here's a reconstruction of your map-drawing function using loops.

```
world_map = [
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'K'],
]


def draw_map(world_map):
    width = len(world_map[0])
    header = "---".join(["+"] * (width + 1))  # Compute header line.
    for row in world_map:
        print(header)  # Print header leading each line.
        print("| {} |".format(" | ".join(row)))  # Format and print the row.
    print(header)  # Print final header (well, footer).


draw_map(world_map)
```

Okay, cool beans, now what about the player character?

In general, games like this are structured in a way that your moving entities, such as characters, enemies, etc. are separate entities and the static map is stored in an array like yours.

Firstly, we'll need a modification to the `draw_map` function so we can keep track of each X/Y coordinate as we render the map:

```
def draw_map(world_map):
    width = len(world_map[0])
    header = "---".join(["+"] * (width + 1))  # Compute header line.
    for y, row in enumerate(world_map):
        print(header)  # Print header leading each line.
        # Figure out which characters to print in each cell.
        chars = []
        for x, c in enumerate(row):
            chars.append(str(c))
        print("| {} |".format(" | ".join(chars)))
    print(header)  # Print final header (well, footer).
```

(The output is still the same.)

Now let's store the hero position in a variable, `hero_position` sounds good enough. Let's also figure out a position for a big evil monster, and come up with some suitable characters for the two. And now for the rendering magic... Since each cell of the map can only render one thing – either the ground tile or the hero or the evil thing, we can pass their coordinates in as a dict, `character_positions` (and if you have a `list` of characters, it's easy to form such a dict).

The magic is `character_positions.get()` here with the second parameter; basically, we see if the x/y coordinate we're drawing exists in the coordinates dict, and use that character instead.

```
def draw_map(world_map, character_positions):
    width = len(world_map[0])
    header = "---".join(["+"] * (width + 1))  # Compute header line.
    for y, row in enumerate(world_map):
        print(header)  # Print header leading each line.
        # Figure out which characters to print in each cell.
        chars = []
        for x, c in enumerate(row):
            chars.append(str(character_positions.get((x, y), c)))
        print("| {} |".format(" | ".join(chars)))
    print(header)  # Print final header (well, footer).

hero_position = (1, 1)  # 0, 0 would be boring.
evil_position = (5, 6)
hero_character = '@'
evil_character = '%'

draw_map(world_map, character_positions={
    hero_position: hero_character,
    evil_position: evil_character,
})
```

The result now is

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | @ |   | T |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   | T |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | T |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   | T | % |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   | K |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

As you can see, the `@` and `%` appeared there!

And now, the interactivity – for the simple case here, let's just use `input()` in a loop to ask the user what to do and modify `hero_position` accordingly.

```
while True:
    draw_map(world_map, character_positions={
        hero_position: hero_character,
        evil_position: evil_character,
    })
    command = input("WASDQ?").lower()
    if command == "w" and hero_position[1] > 0:
        hero_position = (hero_position[0], hero_position[1] - 1)
    if command == "a" and hero_position[0] > 0:
        hero_position = (hero_position[0] - 1, hero_position[1])
    if command == "s" and hero_position[1] < len(world_map) - 1:
        hero_position = (hero_position[0], hero_position[1] + 1)
    if command == "d" and hero_position[0] < len(world_map[0]) - 1:
        hero_position = (hero_position[0] + 1, hero_position[1])
    if command == "q":
        break
    if hero_position == evil_position:
        print("You were eaten!")
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But what is character_positions that you defined?

Comment: As I explain in the post, it's a dict mapping each cell coordinate to something to draw.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to store the `coordinates` of the position of your hero, not what is at that location:

```py
def move(world_map,map_grid):
    hero_position = (0, 0)
    move_direction = input("Press WASD to move: ")
    if move_direction == "d":
        hero_position = hero_position[0], hero_position[1] + 1
        print(hero_position)
```